# Best practice for communitcating between modules

Tags: android, multithreading, interface, module, callback

From a software engineers view, code should be devided in modules. So did i in a project. There are the classical three modules Model-View-Controller (as the widely known pattern). In the controller are some actions that take a long time (for example a sync of the model) and some which are very short (changing the local model for example).

What's the best way to publish results/changes to the view via **one interface**?

In my understanding, the long actions as syncing with a server should run in a seperate Thread as a Service. But using a similar Thread for manipulating the local model would waste resource in my eyes - since this will be (also in future in this case) a quick operation.

Comment: this question is too broad, there are tons of articles regarding `MVC`,`MVP` in `Android` on the net. The concrete decision is up to you and depends on the app you want to build

Comment: @nikis Why? The question is not what main pattern is best for an app but how to make a universal interface that is usable for threaded/non-threaded communication.

Answer (score 0):

Android has Loaders/CursorAdapter - that works really well in keeping UI and data loading independently.

You can have a thread(Volley netowrking lib) that will sync data and update the Database - and then the DB(ContentProvider) will notify any "observing" Cursors to update the UI.

Lookup Loaders/Cursor Adapter and Volley.

Comment: I understand the concept and agree partly: View calls Controller, controller updates Model, and model invalidates displayed content. But i'm not sure wheter this is also ressource waste because invalidating a cursor will force the view to reload the **whole** data.